# PySpark: Pick values from lookup table for computation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames and want to create the output DataFrame from these two.
The DataFrames shown in tabular form as follows:

Input:

Person data:

| Person | flagA | FlagB | FlagC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | True | False | True |
| P2 | False | True | False |
| P3 | True | True | False |

Flag Values:

| Flags | Value |
| --- | --- |
| FlagA | 7.8 |
| FlagB | 8.2 |
| FlagC | 6.5 |

Output expected:
Person Values

| Person | FlagAval | FlagBval | FlagCval | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 7.8 | 0.0 | 6.5 | 14.3 |
| P2 | 0.0 | 8.2 | 0.0 | 8.2 |
| P3 | 7.8 | 8.2 | 0.0 | 16.0 |

Answer (score 2):

UDF is overkill - this can be done using an unpivot, join and pivot:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = person.selectExpr(
    'Person', 
    "stack(3, 'FlagA', FlagA, 'FlagB', FlagB, 'FlagC', FlagC) as (Flags, val)"
).join(
    flag, 
    'Flags'
).groupBy('Person').pivot('Flags').agg(
    F.first(
        F.when(F.col('val'), F.col('Value')).otherwise(0)
    )
).withColumn(
    'Total', 
    F.col('FlagA') + F.col('FlagB') + F.col('FlagC')
)

result.show()
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Person|FlagA|FlagB|FlagC|Total|
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    P1|  7.8|  0.0|  6.5| 14.3|
|    P2|  0.0|  8.2|  0.0|  8.2|
|    P3|  7.8|  8.2|  0.0| 16.0|
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: This worked with some modifications for me and I have two observations. With small dataframe the performance is less than the previous method suggested by "pltc" and the result needs to be sorted as somehow the original order is not preserved. I will try this with larger data sets and compare the performance. Your method is shorter to code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks harder than I thought :). I have to use UDF to turn each True/False flag to its proper value

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ('P1', True, False, True),
        ('P2', False, True, False),
        ('P3', True, True, False),
    ])
    .toDF(['person', 'FlagA', 'FlagB', 'FlagC'])
)

flag_df = (spark
    .sparkContext
    .parallelize([
        ('FlagA', 7.8),
        ('FlagB', 8.2),
        ('FlagC', 6.5),
    ])
    .toDF(['flag', 'value'])
)

flags = {r['flag']: r['value'] for r in flag_df.collect()}

def convert_flag_to_value(flag):
    return flags[flag]

(df
    .withColumn('FlagA', F
        .when(F.col('FlagA') == True, F.udf(convert_flag_to_value, T.DoubleType())(F.lit('FlagA')))
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    .withColumn('FlagB', F
        .when(F.col('FlagB') == True, F.udf(convert_flag_to_value, T.DoubleType())(F.lit('FlagB')))
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    .withColumn('FlagC', F
        .when(F.col('FlagC') == True, F.udf(convert_flag_to_value, T.DoubleType())(F.lit('FlagC')))
        .otherwise(0)
    )
    .withColumn('Total', F.col('FlagA') + F.col('FlagB') + F.col('FlagC'))
    .show())

# +------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |person|FlagA|FlagB|FlagC|Total|
# +------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |    P1|  7.8|  0.0|  6.5| 14.3|
# |    P2|  0.0|  8.2|  0.0|  8.2|
# |    P3|  7.8|  8.2|  0.0| 16.0|
# +------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```